# Multiple objects with NIB in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nib, multiple-instances

I have a noob-question, that might be similar to [Dynamically create multiple instances of a UIView from a NIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280319/dynamically-create-multiple-instances-of-a-uiview-from-a-nib) but I'm missing the big picture.

I've got a class with NIB, called UserViewController and I need to create multiple instances, based on the number of users, store them in an array and be able to modally navigate between them.

A class with NIB, called SelectNumberOfUsersViewController contains this IBACTION-code:

```
users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<numberOfUsers; i++) {
    user = [[UserViewController alloc] init];
    user.userid = i+1;
    [user doInitialization];
    [users addObject:user];
}
```

I see that the `initWithNibName` of the instance `user` is run, but how do I address and show the UI for the first user in the `users` array?
I'm not sure if commands like

```
myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XXX" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[[self view] addSubview:searchDateView]
```

should be used, since the array contains entire objects of the class User with NIB and everything - or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to initialise a viewcontroller with a nib file you should use:

```
user = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
```

If you want to push that view you could call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:user animated:true];
```

To present it, call:

```
[self presentModalViewController:user animated:true];
```

If you just want to add the view to the current viewcontroller use:

```
[self.view addSubView:user.view];
```

But the sure to remove the previous one too.

I hope this was of any help.